# Is there a more efficient way to setup multi-module Java WAR projects in VSCode?

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code

I inherited a multi-module Maven project that had been maintained using Eclipse, and now I really want to use VSCode instead.

It seems the VSCode best practice (based on this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R9mugpHWr14)) is to run `mvn war:exploded` and then right-click `target/classes` to launch each of the modules into Tomcat.

This is very laborious for a project with several modules, and also time-consuming considering I need to run `mvn package` before `mvn war:exploded` every time the code is changed.

Is there a way to setup VSCode to remove some or all of the recurring manual steps, and provide an experience that feels more like incremental compile & hot-deploy?

**TL;DR**

How can VSCode be setup to be as productive and convenient as Eclipse for complex Java multi-module projects?

Comment: Do you mean you want a feature like multi-select modules then go on next steps instead of selecting them one by one? You may put a feature request in [microsoft/vscode-maven](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-maven/issues).

Comment: I just started using VSCode, so I don't really know whether this is a How-To or a Feature Request. Ultimately I would like to remove repetitive manual steps, i.e. when I edit code, the changes would be quickly reflected in the local deploy, without me having to do anything manual to re-build and re-deploy. Given the popularity of VSCode, my initial assumption is that there must be a way to do this. Eclipse has supported this since the early 2000's.

Comment: `mvn war:exploded` why do you need that every time you change your code? Do you use tests?

Comment: @khmarbaise I have to run the `mvn war:exploded` to update the files in the `classes\appname` folder which are read by Tomcat. Are you asking a rhetorical question, i.e. are you saying there is a way to avoid this or that I shouldn't have to use it?

Comment: @AlexR. It indeed can automatically rebuild project if you add or remove dependencies, but the feature in your origin question i can't find in extension **maven for java**, so i suggest you to put a feature request in github. If the feature already exists, you may get answer in github.

Answer (score 2):

> in the hopes there there is a little-known extension or ways to configure VSCode for parity with Eclipse.

And... [I do not see any extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=maven+module&target=VSCode&category=All+categories&sortBy=Relevance) matching this description: [`microsoft/vscode-maven` issue 821](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-maven/issues/821) opened in Aug. 2022 is still opened ("Is there a way to create Multi-Module Maven in VSCode?").

For now, you might consider automating the build and deployment process through [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/guides/index.html).
You can use Maven profiles and lifecycle phases to automatically handle the build (`mvn package`) and deployment (`mvn war:exploded`) steps. Create a script or use Maven plugins to trigger these commands upon code changes.

```xml
<!-- In your pom.xml -->
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>auto-deploy</id>
        <activation>
            <!-- Activation configuration (if needed) -->
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <!-- Configure your build and deploy plugins here -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- Configuration for war:exploded -->
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Since Maven does not directly support watching files for changes, you can use a simple shell script to monitor file changes and trigger Maven commands.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
    # Check for file changes in src directory
    change=$(inotifywait -r -e modify,create,delete --format '%w%f' src/)

    echo "Detected change in $change"
    # Run Maven commands
    mvn -Pauto-deploy clean package war:exploded

    # Optional: Restart Tomcat or deploy to a server
done
```

That script uses [`inotifywait`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait) (as in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/323919/7490)) to monitor changes in the `src/` directory. When a change is detected, it runs Maven with the `auto-deploy` profile. You will need to install [`inotify-tools`](https://github.com/inotify-tools/inotify-tools/wiki) to use `inotifywait`.

---

> It's still not a true incremental build

Incremental builds involve only compiling and deploying the parts of the project that have changed, rather than rebuilding the entire project each time. That can be challenging to implement manually, but can be achieved with the right setup.

Maven does not natively support incremental builds in the way modern build tools like Gradle do. However, you can use the `maven-compiler-plugin` with its [incremental compilation feature](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#useIncrementalCompilation). That plugin only recompiles the classes that have changed or are affected by changes.

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <useIncrementalCompilation>true</useIncrementalCompilation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Other plugins -->
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Modify the script to better detect changes and only trigger the necessary Maven goals for affected modules. That requires a more sophisticated script that can determine which modules have changed and only execute Maven commands for those modules.
As an example:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Function to determine affected modules
determine_changed_modules() {
    # Logic to determine which modules have changed
    # Returns a list of changed modules
}

while true; do
    change=$(inotifywait -r -e modify,create,delete --format '%w%f' src/)
    echo "Detected change in $change"

    # Determine which modules are affected
    changed_modules=$(determine_changed_modules "$change")

    # Run Maven commands only for affected modules
    for module in $changed_modules; do
        mvn -pl $module -am clean package war:exploded
    done

    # Optional: Restart Tomcat or deploy to a server for affected modules
done
```

For complex projects with many modules and interdependencies, achieving a true incremental build can be intricate. In such cases, consider using a build tool like Gradle, which has more advanced support for incremental builds.

Comment: Thank you. I've decided to award you the 50 points reputation but still leave the answer unselected for now. Because although your answer gets me closer to a solution, it's still not a true incremental build. I will leave the question open in case things change in the future and a correct answer emerges.

Comment: @AlexR OK, I have edited the answer to try and get closer to a true incremental build.

Answer (score 0):

Did you get the [Extension Pack for Java](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack) (extension ID : `vscjava.vscode-java-pack`) ?

It includes many extension like :

```
 Language Support for Java™ by Red Hat
    Code Navigation
    Auto Completion
    Refactoring
    Code Snippets
 Debugger for Java
    Debugging
 Test Runner for Java
    Run & Debug JUnit/TestNG Test Cases
 Maven for Java
    Project Scaffolding
    Custom Goals
 Project Manager for Java
    Manage Java projects, referenced libraries, resource files, packages, classes, and class members
 Visual Studio IntelliCode
    AI-assisted development
    Completion list ranked by AI
```

Did you mean the following equivalent in VSCode of this in Eclipse :
[image: servers view eclipse]

If so, the [following extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tomcat-jetty) could help.

Comment: Thank you. I did use this, but it doesn't address the main issue of having to do a bunch of stuff manually.

Comment: Yes I was not sure what was the issue, I completed the answer to better understand your need :)

Comment: Yes, your 2nd screenshot is part of the functionality I'm alluding to. But it goes beyond just the ability to launch a single Tomcat server which is what your screenshot shows. It's also what happens after you launch it. In Eclipse you get "hot code replace" for very fast edit/test cycles without having to run a time-consuming build process each time, and the code can be organized into multiple Maven modules (effectively, separate projects which link together through CLASSPATH settings).

Comment: I'm a huge fan of eclipse for that kind of functionnality even if now, with SB applications and embedded servers,.I don't use this anymore. I've added another link in the answer. Maybe you'll find something interesting in that extension